# Cannot install Aptana Studio 3.6 on Windows

Tags: ruby, installation, aptana, aptana3

I'd like to use Aptana Studio for Rails development under Windows. I currently have different dev tools & ide's up and running (like git/ruby/jdk) and I'd like to install Aptana Studio as well but I can't. After downloading and running installer, it starts properly and after I choose destination dir, it starts downloading prequisities. I have several problems with it:

1. After a while, it tries to install node.js (well, I am not sure why, but let it be) and sometimes it installs it ok, but sometimes it just fails with no error, telling me only that aptana couldn't install prequisities.
2. If by a chance node.js is installed, it tries to install msysgit (again, I don't know why, because I have git installed and added to PATH). When installing msysgit is done, all i get is info that "installing msysgit failed" and all I can do is click finish in installer which is telling me that prequisities couldn't be installed.

I am using Win7 x64, ruby 1.9.3p-545, msysgit 1.8.4, jdk 1.7. Does anyone had simmilar problem and succesfully installed this ide?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Installing Aptana Studio in passive mode bypasses the installation of Git for Windows and Node.js.

```
Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1 /passive /norestart
```

(I am unsure whether Aptana Studio will work properly without those "prerequisites", but it appears to.)

If you want a global installation in a specific directory, the command line is

```
Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1.exe /passive /norestart ALLUSERS=1 APPDIR=c:\apps\AptanaStudio
```

Comment: most helpful! For others who are wondering how to do this, Open command prompt on the place where you have the Aptana Studio installation file and type this command as it is. then press enter. You wont get any notifications after that. Look in the installation place. Usually "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\" for the exe file.

Comment: @Ram: I expect that putting `start /wait` at the beginning of the line will let you see when the installer has finished.

Comment: 2 questions about that (thanks for the hint by the way), is there any way to define the install location with this? I dont want it to be installed in my userfolder... and secondly, why's there no option in the installer at all *facepalm*

Comment: If this is not the most extreme expression of life in windows i do not know what is. Thanks!

Comment: I've got no error but the installed have done nothing, as well

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem. I solved by installing NodeJS from this link: http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows
and Git latest version from https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Finally I was able to run the Aptana installer with no problems.

Answer (score 21):

I have some issue, the fix is:

1. Uninstall any nodejs version.
2. Install https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/x64/node-v0.10.36-x64.msi.
3. Install Aptana.
4. Code...

greetings!

Comment: excelent I followed th steps and works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: The "go.aptana" download link for nodejs is no longer valid, but the above method worked for me to get Aptana installed on a Windows 10 (x64) machine in May 2017. I also installed Git as Orejano suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 17):

Most of us will run into this problem. This can be solved by installing NodeJS from http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows. My Aptana installation installed the GIT automatically but if you still find trouble then I would suggest to install the GIT latest version yourself and rerun the Aptana installation.

Comment: Downloading from your link fixed this issue for me.

Comment: the mentioned link is broken

Answer (score 4):

Install NODE.JS on windows before installing aptana

Try the following link
http://blueashes.com/2011/web-development/install-nodejs-on-windows/

Answer (score 3):

If your issue is related to a failed Windows install,  and you are receiving a message related to installer `_jsnode_windows.msi CRC error`:

> Aptana Studio (Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044) currently
>   requires `Nodejs 0.5.XX-0.11.xx`

Even though the current release of nodejs seems to be `5.X.X` .   Apparently there will be a new release in Nov 2015 that corrects this defect.

Pre-installing `x0.10.36-x64` allowed me to proceed with a successful install.   If version numbers can be believed,   this seems to be an ancient release of `nodejs`,   but hey - I saw a very impressive demo of `Aptana Studio` and really wanted to install it. :-)

I also pre-installed `GIT` for windows,   but I'm not sure if that was necessary or not.

Comment: I ran into this same issue on both windows 8.1 and windows 10.   Both PCs had the same issue,  and the solution posted above worked for both.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, create the folder you want to extract Aptana Studio to, and then use this command:

```
Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1.exe /extract:"folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems having *msysgit* (*Git for Windows*) installed is causing the problem.

In most cases you'll have a pretty recent version of *Git for Windows* installed.
Cited from https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/:

> There was a security issue in Git, see [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1853266). Git for Windows < 1.9.5 is affected - so you should update, TortoiseGit itself is not affected (using the default configuration; only if libgit2 is manually enabled for checkout/fetching). TortoiseGit 1.8.13.0 includes all fixes.

**But it seems *Aptana Studio Installer* won't accept any pre-installed version of *Git for Windows*!**

What you need to do:

1. Uninstall *Git for Windows*.
2. Install *Aptana Studio*.
   *Apanta Studio 3.6.1* will install *Git for Windows 1.8.4-preview20130916*.
3. Download latest version of *Git for Windows* from http://msysgit.github.io/.
4. Install latest version of *Git for Windows*.
   The outdated *Git for Windows 1.8.4-preview20130916* will be updated to recent version.

That's it !!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was because of limited internet connection to source. You can use a proxy (VPN) but the better solution is download manually NodeJs from the source https://nodejs.org/download/ and Git, too.

after installation manually, aptana will check if they installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem installing Aptana 3.6.1 on my windows machine. It always shows "fail to locate node.js installer missing windows msi" No matter how many times I tried to.

Here is how I solved the problem:

1. Install Git: This link is for windows and will automatically have the file ready to dowload 
   https://git-scm.com/download/win
2. Instead of installing the latest version, I chose a little earlier version (also 3) but it's 3.2.2 instead of 3.61 (the current one on the Aptana page) :
   http://www.filehorse.com/download-aptana/11489/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use portable git not installer.Extract the folder to Program Files and rename the folder name from PortableGit to Git.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error initially. so.. pre-installed git and node.js and later installed Aptana, which installed perfectly. Rajeeva.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Win 8.1, and have installed Aptana easily, and use for PHP programming without any issues.
And just experimented with Ruble enhancement to the UI.
All seems to work just fine.

3.6.0.201407100658

Answer (score -1):

Right click the installer and choose "Run as administrator". I suspect it needs administrator account to download and install Node JS during installation.