# Aptana won't load due to CRC error

Tags: html

I am trying to download a simple HTML editor, Aptana,and I keep getting the following error, "Failed to aquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file:CSC error." Has anyone encountered this before? If so, what's the workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://nodejs.org/en/ and download and install node.js. Try your installation again. There are other users who have had slightly different problem than yours and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514458/cannot-install-aptana-studio-3-6-on-windows)'s how they solved it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the answer led you to solve the problem, please feel free to put closure to your question by marking it accepted. If it didn't help, feel free to wait for a better answer.