# Installation issues with Aptana Studio3 standalone

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I downloaded Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1 from this URL: http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html
When I run the exe file, after a while it get's stuck and comes up with this error message:

> "Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file:CRC error."

I am not sure what is happening. I hope someone can advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved by installing NodeJS from this link: http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows and Git latest version.

Credits: Orejano

Answer (score 0):

There is a more complete answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514458/cannot-install-aptana-studio-3-6-on-windows?rq=1&newreg=0414f6de54984de28833c91783eec4d9). I had the same issue and already had nodejs & msysgit installed.