# Install APTANA failed Windows 10

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Aptana studio 3 on my pc, Windows 10. I download the setup from your link and then launch the setup, but after few seconds I have this error: "Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file:CRC error".
After that the setup ends because of the error...how can I solve that?
Thanks for your kind help, I'd like to use Aptana for my study.

Comment: I don't understand the mindless downvotes here. The issue is real, the installer of Aptana is messed up, and the linked topic hasn't worked in my case as well. The description is complete, what more details are expected to be given if there are none? The fact there's no working solution doesn't justify downvotes...

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution posted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514458/cannot-install-aptana-studio-3-6-on-windows?rq=1&newreg=0414f6de54984de28833c91783eec4d9) worked for me. I already had nodejs & msysgit installed.

Comment: You've got luck. It didn't work for me. It's time to forget Aptana, if they are unable to provide a working installer. A shame, it was a good tool once...