# Aptana Studio 3 installation error: Error reading from file

Tags: installation, aptana3

While trying to install aptana for the first time, I faced the following error.

> Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error.

Then I searched for this file from my windows and installed it.  Then trying to install aptana fails with another error.

> Error reading from file: ..\feature.properties.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

I am installing aptana with admin access.  Now struck up with this error.  Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the functionality that you need:
[Cannot install Aptana Studio 3.6 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514458/cannot-install-aptana-studio-3-6-on-windows)

It will force the install.

Comment: Yes, I already went through other questions related to Aptana installation issues, but the one I'm facing is not addressed in any of those.  Hence, I had to post a new question.  Now, again I tried uninstalling node.js, reinstalling it followed by aptana installation.  Still facing the same error "Error reading from file...".  Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Might help if you add windows version, if there were errors that cropped up while installing node.js (what version you installed/where it came from). Most people received the first error, and either attempted to install node.js from the web, or went straight to the force install (since they had to force it even after node.js was installed), in the multiple times I've installed Aptana on different machines this was the process and it worked. In general since none else has reported the later issue, it's an issue with the installer file. Try re-downloading (save to your HD then install).

Comment: I tried re-downloading the installation file and again facing same error "error reading file from..".  I tried to ignore all these kind of errors during installation and installation was completed.  But I couldn't find aptana app to run from my desktop.  While checking in control panel, it says that Aptana is installed.  Wondering what is happening ...